# XSLT for Multiple Child structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I am converting XML to HTML using XSLT.

Here is my running code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <product>
       <auto>
           <admin>
             <date>2015</date>
             <age>28</age>
             <level>3</level>
             <subject>
                <id>1</id>        
             </subject>
           </admin>
           <report>
             <Fname>John</Fname>
             <Lname>AA</Lname>
             <subject>
                <id>1</id>        
             </subject>
           </report>
        </auto>
        <auto>
          <admin>
             <date>02/02/2015</date>
             <age>29</age>
             <level>2</level>
             <subject>
                 <id>1</id>       
             </subject>
          </admin>
          <report>
             <Fname>Jack</Fname>
             <Lname>BB</Lname>
          </report>
        </auto>
     </product>
```

Here is my Running XSLT

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <![CDATA[
    function toggleDisplay(element) 
    {        
        element.style.display = element.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; 
    };
    function toggleDisplayAll(elements) 
    { 
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            toggleDisplay(elements[i]);
        }
    }   
  ]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="product/auto">
    <ul>
    <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">
    <xsl:value-of select="report/Fname"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="admin"/>
    <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="report"/>-->
    </ul>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="date">
   <li style="display:none;">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Date : ',.)"/>
   </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="age">
   <li style="display:none;">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('Age : ',.)"/>
   </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="level">
   <li style="display:none;">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('Level : ',.)"/>
   </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="id">
   <li style="display:none;">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('ID : ',.)"/>
   </li>
</xsl:template> 
 <xsl:template match="subject">
    <li style="display:none;">
       <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')); return false;" href="#">
          <xsl:text>Subject: </xsl:text>
       </a>
       <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
       </ul>
     </li>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="admin">
    <ul  style="display:none;">
       <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')); return false;" href="#">
         <xsl:text>Admin: </xsl:text>
       </a>
       <ul style="display:none;">
         <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
       </ul>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is returning me like

> ```
>      John
>      Jack
> ```

after click on John

> ```
>      John
>          . Admin:             
>      Jack
> ```

On click of Admin

> ```
>      John
>          . Admin:
>              . Date: 2015
>              . Age: 28
>              . Level: 3
>              . Subject:             
>      Jack
> ```

but Subject is a link, I want to display id as a child element on click of it as below

> ```
>      John
>          . Admin:
>              . Date: 2015
>              . Age: 28
>              . Level: 3
>              . Subject:
>                    .Id:  1             
>      Jack
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add template for date, age, level, id, state and country.
Then apply template on child of admin and report instead of a value-of.

By "add template", I mean (not tested, may have 'typo') :

```
<xsl:template match="date">
     <li><xsl:value-of select="concat('Date : ',.)"/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Add similar templates for each element (actually you could use a generic one which could use the element name, but tried to stay simple in my answer).

Then the admin template :

```
<xsl:template match="admin">
 <ul style="display:none;">
  <li>
    <xsl:text>Admin: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
    <br/>
  </li>
</ul>
 </xsl:template>
```

Do the same for the report template.

Comment: Thanks for answering Eric, I did tried by adding as you suggested but it is giving me the same data. Please have a look at changes made and suggest me where i did wrong.

Comment: This is my first assignment in XSLT so need your assistance here.

Comment: Issues are in the HTML outputted, I think. What do you want as html output ?

Comment: Yes, I want a HTML output. Please help me

Comment: Please refer my latest xml and xslt .. i am able to achive one more layer but it is failing in Subject tag.